# How to programmatically trigger flyway migration before spring-boot flyway-ootb migration is executed?

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

In my spring-boot project I'm using out-of-the-box integration for Flyway (`org.flywaydb.flyway-core`) and have some migration scripts which are executed on startup and managed via default `flyway_schema_history`-table.

The project also uses a module bringing its own flyway migration scripts, which are migrated programmatically and keeping track of migrations in an other `moduleX_schema_history`-table.

As the migrations of the main-project needs to work on some of the tables created via the modules migration, the module-migration needs to happen before the flyway-plugin migrates the main-projects scripts.

How can I achieve executing modules migration programmatically and before the main-apllications fly-integration kicks in?
How and when is the flyway-plugin migration triggered?

//EDIT:
I tried to execute code before FlywayAutoConfiguration via a `@Configuration` class annotated with

```
@AutoConfigureBefore({FlywayAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but unfortunatly the class is still instanciated after `FlywayAutoConfiguration`.

//EDIT:
I asked the related (more general) question how to order AutoConfiguration from modules, too [How to use @AutoConfigureOrder in a spring boot configuration class from a module - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63135799/how-to-use-autoconfigureorder-in-a-spring-boot-configuration-class-from-a-modul)

Comment: what do you mean by spring boot flyway plugin? Are you referring to the maven plugin?

Comment: no I mean the out-of-the-box integration for Flyway (sorry for beeing unclear about that)

Answer (score 2):

Flyway migration will kick-in during startup if you configured it correctly in your application yaml/properies file.

In order to start another flyway migration before the main app migration you can use flyway command line or create an separate `custom_pom.xml` project file for another module and trigger it via mvn plugin from command line: `mvn flyway:migrate` before executing the main app.

Comment: flyway migration of the main app does kick in on startup, but how, when/were is it triggered?
unfortunatly command line or maven are not the desired option - the modules migration must happen programatically and before the ootb-pluging does its work.

Comment: When you add flyway dependency and flyway entries in your application config, springboot will try to autoconfigure flyway instance and run it during application startup (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.html). If you want to have more granulated control on how it is initialized and started go with programmatic initialization: https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/api

Comment: thanks. helpful to see, were flyway-core does its magic. But is there no way to trigger code-execution before FlywayAutoConfiguration is loaded by spring autoconfiguration? Like a beforeFlywayAutoConfigurationHook ^^

Comment: You can disable FlywayAutoConfiguration by spring and do the migration by yourself. Do you want that?

Comment: no, the FlywayAutoConfiguration-triggered migration should still be done, but only after the other migration has happened programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question about how to programmatically trigger a Flyway migration and figured out how to do it.  The provided `FlywayMigrationInitializer` runs the Flyway migrations at bean creation time by default, which is what we're trying to prevent.  To get around this, we can override the `FlywayMigrationInitializer`'s `afterPropertiesSet` method to do nothing, and then call `Flyway.migrate()` from the desired location in your code.  Your impl of the `FlywayMigrationInitializer` must be declared as a Bean.

Why is this useful?  You might need to run migrations when:

- at startup only if a certain argument is passed to the application on startup (my use case), or if a certain env variable is set
- an endpoint is called
- on receiving a Kafka event
- at a scheduled time

How I did it:

Add the dependency to build.gradle (similar for Maven pom.xml):

```
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
```

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: true 
    baseline-version: 0 # Needed so you can run a migration that starts with 'V1__'
  ...
```

FlywayConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway,
                                                        ObjectProvider<FlywayMigrationStrategy> migrationStrategy) {
        return new MyFlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, migrationStrategy.getIfAvailable());
    }
}
```

MyFlywayMigrationInitializer:

```
public class MyFlywayMigrationInitializer extends FlywayMigrationInitializer {

    public MyFlywayMigrationInitializer(Flyway flyway,
                                            FlywayMigrationStrategy migrationStrategy) {
        super(flyway, migrationStrategy);
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // no-op.  We don't want to run the migrations at startup
        log.debug("Not running Flyway migrations at application startup");
    }
```

MigrationRunner:

```
public class MigrationRunner {

    public void runMigrations() {
        MigrateResult result = null;
        try {
            result = flyway.migrate(); // runs the migrations
        } catch (FlywayException e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("no schema history table")) { // need to run baseline first to set up the table
                flyway.baseline(); // then try to run the migrations again
                result = flyway.migrate();
            } else {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        // optionally do something with the result
    }
}
```