# How to use @AutoConfigureOrder in a spring boot configuration class from a module

Tags: spring-boot, module, spring-autoconfiguration

In my spring boot project I use a module, which provides a `@Configuration` class. The configuration ist imported via `@Import(ConfigurationFromModule.class)` in `Application` class.

The configuration from the module needs to happen before a certain `AutoConfiguration`. Unfortunately annotations defining the order of configurations seem to be ignored in the modules classes.

I annotated the Configuration with `@AutoConfigureBefore({SomeBuildInAutoConfiguration.class})`, but still `SomeBuildInAutoConfiguration` was triggered before `ConfigurationFromModule`.

Out of curiosity I tried to annoatate `ConfigurationFromModule` with `@AutoConfigureOrder(1)` and `@Primary` - but they don't change anything.

For `@Configuration`classes within the main applications all those annotations work as expected.

How to define order of AutoConfiguration within a module?

Answer (score 0):

Spring AutoConfiguration provides a basic configuration if certain classes are in the classpath or not.

If you want that configuration in order you can make use of `@DependsOn`

```
@DependsOn("One") 
public class Two{
    
}
```

This helps you to create bean "One", then bean "Two".

Spring automatically detects the dependencies by analyzing the bean classes.

If Bean One has an autowired property or a constructor argument of type Two, spring knows that it must instantiate Two before One.

Comment: DependsOn is the other way round - I need to have my custom class from module loaded before a build-in-autoconfiguration. DependsOn would only ensure some build-in-autoconfiguration is done before my custom class is  loaded